# Class methods to add the sum of prices using recursion with n depth

Tags: javascript, class, recursion, methods

My question is regarding the `add()` method in `NestedPrice`.
How can I create a recursive function return to the sum of prices in this format: `{ fee: 0, premium: 0 }`?

My understanding now is that array `prices` should be iterated through.
If the next instance is `NestedPrice` then the `add` function should be called to go the next level of depth ie `price.prices`.
While if the next instance is `Price` then the sum `n` price objects would be calculated for both `fee` and `premium`.
The result should be tracked using result and return as an object.
*I've included both parent and child class for reference.

**Child class `NestedPrice` and `task2` function checking `add` method**

```
class NestedPrice extends Price {
  /**
   * The argument `prices` should be an array of instances of
   * the class Price or NestedPrice.
   */
  constructor(prices) {
    super({});
    this.prices = prices;
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add(...prices) {
    return prices.reduce((result, price) => {
      //   console.log(price);
      if (price instanceof NestedPrice) {
        return this.add(result, ...price.prices);
      } else {
        let totalFee = 0;
        let totalPremium = 0;
        for (let [key, value] of price.entries()) {
          totalFee += key.fee;
          totalPremium += key.premium;
        }
        console.log(totalFee, totalPremium);
        return (result = { fee: totalFee, premium: totalPremium });
      }
    }, new Price({ fee: 0, premium: 0 }));
  }
}

function task2() {
  const priceA = new NestedPrice([
    new Price({ fee: 5, premium: 50 }),
    new Price({ fee: 10, premium: 130 }),
  ]);
  const priceB = new NestedPrice([
    new Price({ fee: 10, premium: 70 }),
    new Price({ fee: 0, premium: 30 }),
    new NestedPrice([
      new Price({ fee: 0, premium: 10 }),
      new Price({ fee: 5, premium: 25 }),
    ]),
  ]);

  const result = priceA.add(priceB);

  // result should have a premium of 315 and a fee of 30
  return result;
}

console.log(task2());
```

**Parent class `Price` and `task1` function checking `add` method**

```js
class Price {
  constructor({ fee, premium }) {
    this.fee = fee;
    this.premium = premium;
  }

  add(...prices) {
    prices = [...prices, { premium: this.premium, fee: this.fee }];
    let totalFee = 0;
    let totalPremium = 0;
    for (let instance of prices) {
      totalFee += instance.fee;
      totalPremium += instance.premium;
    }
    return { fee: totalFee, premium: totalPremium };
  }
}

function task1() {
  const priceA = new Price({
    premium: 100,
    fee: 10,
  });
  const priceB = new Price({
    premium: 120,
    fee: 15,
  });
  const priceC = new Price({
    premium: 80,
    fee: 20,
  });

  const result = priceA.add(priceB, priceC);

  // result should have a premium of 300 and a fee of 45
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `NestedPrice` shouldn't extend `Price` if it doesn't have a `.fee` and `.premium` itself, or if its constructor doesn't satisfy the same interface. I would recommend to drop it completely and write only a static method `add` for the `class Price`, to be called as `const priceA = Price.add(new Price(…), new Price(…)); const priceB = Price.add(new Price(…), Price.add(new Price(…), new Price(…))); const result = Price.add(priceA, priceB);`.

Comment: In this situation, I'm forced into using classes. And also classes will become more complicated after I complete this task.

Comment: You're not forced to use classes that inherit from each other. And if the classes will become more complicated later, it's even more important to start out with a design with proper semantics.

Comment: Btw if you're really forced to use classes it's unclear why you accepted an answer that does use any.

Comment: @Bergi I accepted that answer before because it was truly useful to my thought process. But it did not give me the answer I needed to directly. I have come up with a solution on my own. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution using recursion.

Using *'for of loop'* to select elements (`dep`) in the array of NestedPrice and Price.
If **`NestedPrice`** then `self.nested` will call itself and pass in `dep.prices` to go down to the next depth. If **`Price`** then object will be pushed to array and continue to iterate at the current depth.

```js
class Price {
  constructor({ premium, fee }) {
    this.premium = premium;
    this.fee = fee;
  }
  add(...prices) {
    prices.push({ premium: this.premium, fee: this.fee });
    const price = { premium : 0, fee : 0 }
    return prices.reduce((p1,p2) => { 
        price.fee = p1.fee + p2.fee
        price.premium = p1.premium + p2.premium
        return price
     })
  }
}

function task1() {
  const priceA = new Price({
    premium: 100,
    fee: 10,
  });
  const priceB = new Price({
    premium: 120,
    fee: 15,
  });
  const priceC = new Price({
    premium: 80,
    fee: 20,
  });

  const result = priceA.add(priceB, priceC);

  // result should have a premium of 300 and a fee of 45
  return result;
}

console.log("Task1", task1());

/***** TASK 2 *****/

class NestedPrice extends Price {

  constructor(prices) {
    super({});
    this.prices = [...prices];
  }

  nested(price, result) {
    const self = this;
        for (let dep of price) {
            if (dep.constructor.name === 'Price') {
                result.push(dep)
            } else {
                self.nested(dep.prices, result) 
            }
        }
    return result
  }

  add(...prices) {
    const flat = []
    const flatArray = this.nested([...prices, ...this.prices], flat)
    const price = {fee:0, premium:0}
    return flatArray.reduce((p1,p2) => { 
       price.fee = p1.fee + p2.fee
       price.premium = p1.premium + p2.premium
       return price
    })
  }
}

function task2() {
  const priceA = new NestedPrice([
    new Price({ fee: 5, premium: 50 }),
    new Price({ fee: 10, premium: 130 }),
  ]);
  const priceB = new NestedPrice([
    new Price({ fee: 10, premium: 70 }),
    new Price({ fee: 0, premium: 30 }),
    new NestedPrice([
      new Price({ fee: 0, premium: 10 }),
      new Price({ fee: 5, premium: 25 }),
    ]),
  ]);

  const result = priceA.add(priceB);

  // result should have a premium of 315 and a fee of 30
  return result;
}

console.log("Task2", task2());
```

Answer (score 1):

**functional principles**

I would recommend a module approach using functional principles. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignment, and other side effects -

```
// price.js

const price = ({ fee = 0, premium = 0}) =>
  ({ fee, premium })
  
const add2 = (p1, p2) =>
  price({
    fee: p1.fee + p2.fee,
    premium: p1.premium + p2.premium
  })
  
const add = ([p, ...more]) =>
  more.reduce(add2, p)

export { price, add, add2 }
```

**commutative**

Our adding functions have [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) -

```js
add2(A, B) == add2(B, A) == add([A, B]) == add([B, A])
```

**associative**

And [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). These properties allow us to use [equational reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) where our programs can be expressed like formulae and laws can be relied upon for correctness -

```js
add2(A, add2(B, C)) == add2(add2(A, B), C) == add([A, B, C])
```

**demo**

```js
const priceA = price({ premium: 100, fee: 10 })
const priceB = price({ premium: 120, fee: 15 })
const priceC = price({ premium: 80, fee: 20 })

add2(priceA, add2(priceB, priceC))
add2(add2(priceA, priceB), priceC)
add([priceA, priceB, priceC])
```

```js
{ "fee": 45, "premium": 300 }
{ "fee": 45, "premium": 300 }
{ "fee": 45, "premium": 300 }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
// price.js
const price = ({ fee = 0, premium = 0}) =>
  ({ fee, premium })
  
const add2 = (p1, p2) =>
  price({
    fee: p1.fee + p2.fee,
    premium: p1.premium + p2.premium
  })
  
const add = ([p, ...more]) =>
  more.reduce(add2, p)
  
// main.js
const priceA = price({ premium: 100, fee: 10 })
const priceB = price({ premium: 120, fee: 15 })
const priceC = price({ premium: 80, fee: 20 })

console.log(add2(priceA, add2(priceB, priceC)))
console.log(add2(add2(priceA, priceB), priceC))
console.log(add([priceA, priceB, priceC]))
```

**nested**

You are obviously aware of Arrays, but maybe you're not aware of some of their properties -

```
a1.concat(a2).flat(Infinity) == a1.flat(Infinity).concat(arr2.flat(Infinity))
```

This means `NestedPrice` is already done for you. Why do more work when we can already rely on well-defined behaviours?

```js
const priceA = [
  price({ fee: 5, premium: 50 }),
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 130 }),
]

const priceB = [
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 70 }),
  price({ fee: 0, premium: 30 }),
  [
    price({ fee: 0, premium: 10 }),
    price({ fee: 5, premium: 25 }),
  ]
]

add(priceA.flat(Infinity).concat(priceB.flat(Infinity)))
add(priceA.concat(priceB).flat(Infinity))
add([add(priceA.flat(Infinity), add(priceB.flat(Infinity))])
```

```js
{ "fee": 30, "premium": 315 }
{ "fee": 30, "premium": 315 }
{ "fee": 30, "premium": 315 }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
// price.js
const price = ({ fee = 0, premium = 0}) =>
  ({ fee, premium })
  
const add2 = (p1, p2) =>
  price({
    fee: p1.fee + p2.fee,
    premium: p1.premium + p2.premium
  })
  
const add = ([ p, ...more ]) =>
  more.reduce(add2, p)


// main.js
const priceA = [
  price({ fee: 5, premium: 50 }),
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 130 }),
]

const priceB = [
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 70 }),
  price({ fee: 0, premium: 30 }),
  [
    price({ fee: 0, premium: 10 }),
    price({ fee: 5, premium: 25 }),
  ]
]

const r1 =
  add(priceA.flat(Infinity).concat(priceB.flat(Infinity)))

const r2 =
  add(priceA.concat(priceB).flat(Infinity))

const r3 =
  add([add(priceA.flat(Infinity)), add(priceB.flat(Infinity))])

console.log(r1)
console.log(r2)
console.log(r3)
```

**empty price**

Scott's comments brings up a good point. I was going to leave it left unsaid for this post, but we might as well introduce you to the [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) category. I'd say this is a more robust implementation of `price` overall -

```js
// price.js

const price = ({ fee = 0, premium = 0}) =>
  ({ fee, premium })

const empty =                             // <- monoid identity element
  price()

const add = (p1 = empty, p2 = empty) =>   // <- monoid binary function
  price({
    fee: p1.fee + p2.fee,
    premium: p1.premium + p2.premium
  })
  
const sum = (prices = []) =>              // <- better implementation of sum
  prices.reduce(add, empty)

export { price, empty, add, sum }
```

**identity element? binary function?**

The Sum monoid has an identity element of `0` and `+` is the binary function. It's called the *identity* element, because when used in the binary function, it always evaluates to the other argument -

```js
5 + 0 == 5
0 + 9 == 9
```

The Product monoid has and identity element of `1` and `*` is the binary function -

```js
5 * 1 == 5
1 * 9 == 9
```

The Price monoid (hey, that's yours!) has an identity element of `{ fee: 0, premium: 0 }`, or `empty`, and the binary function is `add` -

```js
add(price({ fee: 5, premium: 9 }), empty) == price({ fee: 5, premium: 9 })
add(empty, price({ fee: 5, premium: 9 })) == price({ fee: 5, premium: 9 })
```

By implementing `price` this way, we inherit the properties of the Monoid category and we automatically know how to reason about its behaviour in a practical and familiar way.

**ok, but i really wanted recursion**

Well if you insist -

```js
// price.js
const price = ({ fee = 0, premium = 0}) =>
  ({ fee, premium })
  
const add2 = (p1, p2) =>
  price({
    fee: p1.fee + p2.fee,
    premium: p1.premium + p2.premium
  })
  
// main.js
const priceA = [
  price({ fee: 5, premium: 50 }),
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 130 }),
]

const priceB = [
  price({ fee: 10, premium: 70 }),
  price({ fee: 0, premium: 30 }),
  [
    price({ fee: 0, premium: 10 }),
    price({ fee: 5, premium: 25 }),
  ]
]

const nested = (t, ...more) =>
  Array.isArray(t)
    ? nested(...t, ...more)
: more.length == 0
    ? t
: add2(t, nested(...more))
    
console.log(nested(priceA, priceB))
```

```js
{ "fee": 30, "premium": 315 }
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder if the `p` parameter in `add` should be defaulted to `{fee: 0, premium: 0}`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I wasn't going to go that far but it's _right_ there so might as well :D

Comment: Amazing! Question answered and then some! This is will take a bit to digest :)

Comment: Well, you took this a *lot* further than I meant to suggest.  But I love the gentle introduction to Monoids.  It might be useful to note that commutativity is a very useful property, but not essential to a monoid.

Comment: Would someone like to explain what is happening step by step in the recursion example?

Comment: Scott, the commutativity is unrelated to monoid yes, but associativity is required for monoid binary operation :D